# Rewrite and redirect a url without query string (static) to url with query string parameter

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url suppose

```
http://www.naturaflowers.com/products_new.html
```

I want to rewrite and redirect it to

```
http://www.naturaflowers.com/products_new.html?page=1
```

as both url open the same page. I tried the following but no work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products_new.html [NC]
RewriteRule /products_new.html?page=1 [R=301,L]
```

Please help me to overcome this issue. Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to add the same query string everytime someone accesses the page? Couldn't you just assume that if there is no query string than the user is on page 1?

Comment: @samrap but how is it possible. In this case two url open the same page. I want to redirect one from another. Will you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as **very first rule** in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)page=1\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^products_new\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}?page=1 [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
```

`RewriteCond` is needed to make sure `?page=1` isn't already there.

Comment: @anubhava I need opposite of this. does any body know how to do it?

Comment: @Mahesh: Post a new question and I will try my best to help you.